# Valid Mixing of JPA and Hibernate with Spring based Web Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm taking a look into a new web application that uses Spring and JPA. I was wondering by using the jpaVendorAdapter of org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter, what pieces of Hibernate are really being used or are available through this configuration (see config below)?

When searching the rest of the codebase, I only find POJOs/Entities with caching references to Hibernate in the code. Why use Hibernate cache here?  Are there JPA options that can replace any dependency on Hibernate?

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

**Spring contextConfigLocation file excerpt:**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="pwd" />
    </bean>
```